# How do I handle untyped POST data in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Something is going to call my web server with the url http://testserver.fake.com/responses/123 with a POST.

What I want to do is save the body of the POST to a file such as "\fileserver\response\123.response".

What should the signature look like on the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
  public ActionResult SavePostAction(int responseId)
  {
        // read post data straight from the request.
        string postData = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();

        // create a json file
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
        {
            postData = postData
        });

        // Save the file to your filesystem\db etc..
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"c:\temp\" + responseId + ".reponse", json);

       return new EmptyResult(); // or whatever
  }
```

Comment: I'm looking for the other direction. Reading the data from the POST request and saving the data to the server.